# Threading not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

So! I am just playing around with progress bars in winForm but I noticed something. If I use a For statement the progress bar goes from 0 - 100 instant, even if I put a EX: Thread.Sleep(10000); It waits the time and then goes too 100%.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void progressbar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            progressBar1.Value = i;

        }

    }
```

Comment: You told it to sleep and it did.  Research the BackgroundWorker to do this the right way.

Comment: @LarsTech Certainly will, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread. While your event handler is running, your window can't handle any incoming window messages, so it will not update, and it will not repaint. Don't block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update every interaction your progressbar. Note also that in your for, will go to 90 only and not to 100. Try this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    progressBar1.Value = i;
    progressBar1.Refresh();
}
```

EDIT: 
To work you must put in some event such as the click of a button , never in a Form Load